# Is installing Rails via Debian APT package a best practice?

Tags: linux, debian, ruby, rails

I've been recently reading the Debian website and found a page called Don't Break Debian (https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) where they tell that it is not a best practice to install software outside of apt because it may break when upgrading Debian.

So, is it a best practice to install the Ruby on Rails via rvm/rbenv or utilize the already existent packages on debian apt? (apt-get install rails)

I don't care about the new features, just need security and stability patches.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered a best practice to install Rails through RubyGems, and in general to install and use Ruby and various gems through something like RVM or rbenv. The issue is that the versions packaged in distros tend to be static and not be updated to the latest, most featureful, and most secure versions.